# cron installed by default fails with "exec: fstrim-all: not found"

Tags: 16.04, ssd, cron

`/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim:` is installed by default (confirmed by https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254840/92199)

Unfortunately for me it keeps generating

```
/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim:
/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim: 10: exec: fstrim-all: not found
run-parts: /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim exited with return code 127
```

failures (delivered via local mails).

I have a SSD so I would prefer to avoid just deleting this task.

I [found](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=fstrim-all+package) that fstrim-all used to be in [util-linux package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=fstrim-all) but I already have it installed (and anyway in [xenial it is gone](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=fstrim-all&searchon=contents))

```
mateusz@grisznak:~$ sudo apt-get install util-linux
[sudo] password for mateusz: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
util-linux is already the newest version (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.6).
```

This tool fails not only in cron environment:

```
mateusz@grisznak:~$ fstrim-all
fstrim-all: command not found
```

My system version:

```
mateusz@grisznak:~$ uname -a
Linux grisznak 4.15.0-43-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 7 13:31:08 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How can I get regular `fstrim` working? Or maybe it is OK to delete this task despite that I have SSD?

Comment: Was this upgraded from a previous release? I don't have `fstrim-all` in the `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim` file on a 16.04 machine. Instead it contains `fstrim --all || true`.

Comment: There are no space before --all. Don't remove that cron job, its needed for ssd. You can even make it daily instead of weekly.

Comment: Whats output of `which fstrim` ? May be adding full path to cron job will help

Comment: @Arronical Thanks! It was a fresh install rather than an upgrade, but maybe backup restore managed to override also this file. Can you turn it into the answer?

Comment: @LeonidMew "daily" Can you make a new answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218076/ssd-how-often-should-i-do-fstrim (with some source?) Let me know that you posted answer with a good source and I will give you a bounty.

Comment: Sure thing @MateuszKonieczny. It actually uses the full path to fstrim too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim` file on my 16.04 system contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
# trim all mounted file systems which support it
/sbin/fstrim --all || true
```

This specifies the absolute path to the `fstrim` binary and uses the `--all` option. It's not clear why the version you have differs, though it matches the file I found on a 14.04 installation.